# errors while installing discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

i tried to install discord.py but something went wrong, i don't know why, ,can someone help me?

i have execute this command:
`pip install discord`

right now i'm using python 3.9.0, maybe i should be using version 3.5.3?

MY TERMINAL:

```
PS C:\Users\badreddinelaghlid\Desktop\codaggio con python> pip install discord 
Collecting discord
  Downloading discord-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)
Collecting discord.py>=1.0.1
  Downloading discord.py-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (701 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 701 kB 1.3 MB/s
Collecting aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0
  Downloading aiohttp-3.6.3.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.1 MB 726 kB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0
  Downloading yarl-1.5.1.tar.gz (173 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 173 kB 1.6 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting chardet<4.0,>=2.0
  Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 133 kB 2.2 MB/s
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Downloading attrs-20.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 48 kB 2.2 MB/s
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Downloading async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting multidict<5.0,>=4.5
  Downloading multidict-4.7.6.tar.gz (50 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 50 kB 3.1 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting idna>=2.0
  Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 58 kB 1.7 MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: aiohttp, yarl, multidict
  Building wheel for aiohttp (PEP 517) ... done
  Created wheel for aiohttp: filename=aiohttp-3.6.3-py3-none-any.whl size=440479 sha256=515efabf51ce43d3d161e6a2829a8b366438049af887a441fc5aee702f0830f0
  Stored in directory: c:\users\badreddinelaghlid\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\b6\9c\bd\6b99bc6ec9dab11f3756d31fb8506d3ecf07aea58b6201f539
  Building wheel for yarl (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\badreddinelaghlid\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\badreddinelaghlid\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\BADRED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpz_p_dipv'
       cwd: C:\Users\badreddinelaghlid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ty37tuq6\yarl
  Complete output (35 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.9
  creating build\lib.win32-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\yarl
  running egg_info
  writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.c -> build\lib.win32-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.9\yarl
  running build_ext
  building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
  Building wheel for multidict (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\badreddinelaghlid\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\badreddinelaghlid\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\BADRED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpitmt1bzr'
       cwd: C:\Users\badreddinelaghlid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ty37tuq6\multidict
  Complete output (40 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.9
  creating build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict
  running egg_info
  writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict.c -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict
  creating build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\dict.h -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\istr.h -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\iter.h -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\pair_list.h -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\views.h -> build\lib.win32-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  running build_ext
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Successfully built aiohttp
Failed to build yarl multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for yarl, multidict which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I haven't been coding in a long time so.. I may have forgotten something..

thanks for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the problem: `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`. U need to download it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with `discord.py`and `python3.9` on Windows, see:
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5984

I would recommend you to use `python<=3.8` as `3.9.0` is too new.